# Bug in java.time with Resoverstyle.STRICT

Tags: java, java-time

Either I don't quite grasp what the resolver style in `java.time` does, or there is a bug.

I have the following code (in Scala):

```
import java.sql.Timestamp
import java.time.format.{DateTimeFormatter, ResolverStyle}
import java.time.ZonedDateTime

val str = "2016-07-11T05:45:44.552+04:00"
val iso1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXXXX")
val iso2 = iso1.withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT)

Timestamp.from(ZonedDateTime.parse(str, iso1).toInstant) // works fine
Timestamp.from(ZonedDateTime.parse(str, iso2).toInstant) // nope!
```

The first version works and the second throws the following exception a   `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException`. What I don't understand is why. The date and time are in my opinion valid.

See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/ResolverStyle.html#STRICT

Comment: ideone for the stack; https://ideone.com/5dzPsP, you need to use "u" for the year in strict mode, see the duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

This is incorrect ISO format, just use `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME`.